# .eq() comes back as 'not a function'

Tags: ajax

I am trying to get information from an ajax object. I have the following jquery function inside a .then() method, but I am getting an error that reads "data.items.eq is not a function." I have tried a combination of .eq() and .children(), but they don't seem to work.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + userInput,
      type: "GET",
   }).then(
      (data) => {
         console.log(data);
         $('#book-info').html(data.items.eq(0).volumeInfo.title);
   }
```

![This is the ajax object that I am trying to get the title from.] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2CBO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `data.items[0].volumeInfo.title` instead. `.eq()` is a method of the jQuery object and will not exist for the JavaScript array `data.items`.